# Graphics.DrawString - Incorrect drawing of Combining Diacritical Marcs

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+

I'm trying to draw text, which contains symbols from "Combining Diacritical Marcs" unicode subrange (U+0300 - U+FE23). For example i tried to draw string "T̅", wich contains of two characters: 'T' and '\u0305'.

I've got that:

[image: Incorrect GDI+ render]

Is there any way to get correct text?

Addition: I need to draw rotated text too.

---

PS: my code:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  Graphics g = e.Graphics;
  Font fontTahoma = new Font("Tahoma", 16);
  Font fontTimesNewRom = new Font("Times New Romulan", 16);
  Font fontArial = new Font("Arial", 16);
  Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
  g.DrawString("Test1 T̅ T\u0305", fontTahoma, brush, new PointF(20, 20));
  g.DrawString("Test1 T̅ T\u0305", fontTimesNewRom, brush, new PointF(20, 40));
  g.DrawString("Test1 T̅ N\u0305", fontArial, brush, new PointF(20, 60));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextRenderer seems to draw it better:

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(g, "Test1 T̅ T\u0305", fontTahoma, 
                                            new Point(120, 20), Color.Black);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it looks good. And is it possible to use antialiasing and to draw rotated text?

Comment: @EugeneMaksimov You can try using `g.SmoothingMode` for antialiasing, but you do lose some control of the text output since TextRenderer uses GDI, not GDI+.  You also lose rotation and scaling when it comes to TextRenderer.